# Prove that $\sqrt{-1}=\frac{i}{\pi}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-writing, logarithms

It's highly unlikely but suppose human beings first considered the problem of $\ln{(-1)}$ before $\sqrt{-1}$ and gave $\ln{(-1)}$ the symbol $i$.

Now, can we work our way backwards to show that

$$\sqrt{-1}=\frac{i}{\pi}$$
I don't think that the Taylor series proof of Euler's identity can work backwards.

Comment: The logarithm function is defined as $\log(|z|)+i\arg(z)$ where the argument of $z$ is multivalued.  How are you defining $\log(z)$?

Comment: @Dr.MV Complex numbers don't exist in this world. We've given the symbol $i$ to $\ln{(-1)}$. You can't talk about numbers of the form $a+\sqrt{(-1)}b$. Suppose, square root of negative numbers is not defined yet, only logarithms of negatives are defined. Now, establish the relationship between logarithms and roots of negative numbers.

Comment: So you're trying to propose an alternative complex number system and asking whether we can prove a result that is approximately from our current one?

Comment: @ConMan What do you mean by 'that is approximately from our current one'?

Comment: @Dove I gave the definition of the logarithm in our world.  I asked you for the definition in yours.  What is it?

Comment: @Dr.MV Analogue to complex numbers, in my world the 'complex numbers' are of the form $z=ab^i$ where $i=\ln{(-1)}$. The logarithm of these numbers are defined as $\ln{z}=\ln{a}+i\ln{b}$

Comment: I cannot make any logical sense of your definition.

Comment: @Dr.MV What? It's simply the property of logarithms. $\ln{(ab^c)}=\ln{a}+c\ln{b}$

Comment: How do you add two complex numbers in your world?  And how do you define $b^i$?

Comment: @Dr.MV $ab^i+cd^i$ is simply that and nothing further to be simplified. However, multiplication is good: $ab^i*cd^i=ac(bd)^i$ where $i=\ln{(-1)}$. $b^i$ is simply $b^i$ where $i=\ln{(-1)}$. Can you simplify $ib$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$? Why are you exploring this complex world? My question was: Give $\ln{(-1)}$ the symbol $i$, now prove $\sqrt{(-1)}=\frac{i}{\pi}$.

Answer (score 1):

The given definition is a little problematic, because of

$$\ln(-1)=-\ln\left(\frac1{-1}\right)=-\ln(-1),$$ hence $$i=-i.$$

This needs to be somehow fixed.

Comment: Maybe this problem is similar to this: $-1=i*i=\sqrt{-1*-1}=\sqrt{1}=1$. We made an exception to the rule there. I think an exception rule can be made here, maybe $\ln{\frac{a}{b}}=-\ln{\frac{b}{a}}$ only if both $a$ and $b$ are positive.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your question as it stands is that $i := \ln(-1)$ is not a proper definition.

What we are doing when we are introducing the complex numbers is that we are introducing a new "symbol" $i$ and then let $\Bbb{C} = \{ a + bi \,:\, a,b\in \Bbb{R}\}$. If you don't like the idea of a "symbol" $i$, then let $\Bbb{C} = \{(a,b) \,:\, a,b\in \Bbb{R}\}$ and simply interpret $a+bi$ as another way of writing $(a,b)$.

Then we are **defining** the arithmetic operations $+,\cdot$ on $\Bbb{C}$ in such a way that $i^2 = -1$. But we still have **defined** $+,\cdot$ on all of $\Bbb{C}$.

In your case, you just say "let $i = \ln (-1)$". This gives us no further idea about the properties of $i$. In particular, we don't know how to calculate with it. Also, "$i = \ln(-1)$" is not really meaningful. I guess this to mean $\exp(i) = -1$. But we then still have to define $\exp$ on some set which contains $i$ and $i/\pi$ (since you are considering $i/\pi$, you also have to explain what it means to divide the "symbol" $i$ that you introduced by $\pi$).

---

Finally, there is another problem. Let us assume that your $i := \ln(-1)$ is a complex number. I will write $j$ for the "real" imaginary unit, since you insist on calling your new symbol $i$.

Then, $\exp(i) = -1$. But we also have $\exp(i + 2\pi j) = -1$. So if the only property you have on $i$ is that $\exp(i)=-1$, then you will not be able to show $i / \pi = j$, since the property $\exp(i)=-1$ does **not determine $i$ uniquely**.